# Go to ancestor directory by name

Tags: bash, sh

How can I go to an ancestor directory by name?

I've got some code that searches for a descendant directory by name ("resources" in this case), no matter the exact path.

```
cd "$(find ./ -type d -name "resources" | head -n 1)"
```

I now need to do the same but for the ancestor instead of descendant directories.

Comment: Can you show an example this 'ancestor' case? with some sample paths?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but perhaps something like `cd "$(pwd | grep -o '.*/resources/')"`?

Comment: @biffen that's what I was looking for, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is `dirname` (strip last component)

```
cd "$(find ./ -type d -name "resources" -exec dirname {} \; | head -n 1)"
```